# Mathematics in Deep Learning Theory

Tags: mathematical-statistics, deep-learning

What areas of pure mathematics may give fruitful perspectives with which to develop more theory in the field of deep learning?

(I'm asking about topics at the level of advanced undergraduate and introductory graduate courses.)

Comment: you have to explain your overall goal (are you a math undergraduate looking to do a masters etc). there are many that would argue that deep learning is a purely 'practical' success with little theoretical machine learning let alone mathematical innovation.

Comment: Joan Bruna, [Mathematics of Deep Learning](http://cims.nyu.edu/%7Ebruna/Media/cims_oct19.pdf), Courant Institute, NYU.

Comment: I am a theoretically-inclined undergraduate intending to do a PhD.  I am beginning to see a little bit more theory (coming from many different perspectives) trying to explain the "practical" success of deep learning, so I wanted to know what advanced courses may give further interesting frameworks to think within as a future researcher.  (Even if the link is more speculative, I'm curious to know.)

Comment: undergraduate in what ? computer science/maths/statistics ???

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/202442/deep-learning-deep-neural-nets-for-mathematician

Comment: Tomaso Poggio's course (Last 2 classes) seems interesting http://www.mit.edu/~9.520/fall14/ (from kjetil's link)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the following papers : [Computing with infinite networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1197-computing-with-infinite-networks.pdf), by Christopher K. I. Williams and [Bayesian learning for neural networks](http://www.csri.utoronto.ca/~radford/ftp/thesis.pdf) by Radford M. Neal presenting an interesting relationships between neural networks and gaussian processes.

It is not related to "deep learning" (understood as neural network with multiple layers) but it has a strong mathematical content, related to single layer neural networks with an infinite number of weights.